# Cassandra table data with ttl exipired but disk space not release

Tags: cassandra, ttl

I am using cassandra (DSE4.8), and set the default_time_to_live as 86400(1day), gc_grace_seconds as 180 (3min) on the table, the compaction strategy is STCS.

One day data volume for this table is about 100GB, there is data write in the table every seconds, and I got about 382GB data of the table after 5days. (I use "nodetool cfstats" command to get the table data volume)

[image]

Who can tell me why the ttl not work?

Comment: Did you check if a full repair had been running? You might have zombie data. Check this blog post for more info http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html. Also, note that " as Cassandra operators we have to run a full repair of any cluster performing deletes at least once every gc_grace_seconds"

Comment: forgot one informaton, I just run only 1 node.

Comment: Try to run sstablemetadata to see if you have tombstones https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTableMetadata.html

Comment: @Horia If you look at the last two lines, it's pretty obvious that there definitely are tombstones.

Answer (score 1):

TTLs create tombstones, just like "normal" deletes do.  The tombstones (and the prior data which was deleted) will remain until the setting in your `gc_grace_seconds` has elapsed.

Once that time has passed, that space will be reclaimed the next time compaction runs.  By the look of it, your table has 16 sstable files behind it, so a compaction on it has not yet been triggered.

Comment: If there are 300k expired rows, How they are processed? because of the tombstones limit 100k, the remaining 200k cannot be tombstones..